# Where to place a front-end 'entry form'?

Tags: templating, form, url, routing

I'm trying to add an entry form outside CP (for users with proper permissions), using this example:

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form

but there's no mentioning of how/where to add a page/template that will house the form. One place I was able to place it is the actual template for the entry which is also used for viewing the entry, but that's not what I need. I need a separate URL pattern and separate template file. E.g.:

`mysite.com/recipes/{slug}/edit`

or

`mysite.com/edit-recipes/{slug}`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd put it in your `craft/templates` folder at something like `craft/templates/recipes/new.html`.  Then you'd be able to load that from `http://mysite.com/recipes/new`.

There's a good templating overview in the docs [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating-overview).